# OpenID Sharing Id Token with multiple clients

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have a few web app clients using openid connect authorization code flow, each app have a different client key and secret key. I want to share the ID token with all my web apps, in other words create a session so that user using the browser can use any of the web app without having to authenticate again.

I'm planning to add into the aud (audience) the client id of all of the web app that form part of the session.

Any problem with this?

Can each web app request an access token using the id token?

Answer (score 5):

That's kind of the whole point of having the SSO bits of a OIDC provder. If you're already authenticated against idsrv with one client, you don't have to re-authenticate when you navigate to another client using the same IdentityServer as Id provider.

There might be another redirect, but it should be straight back to the client.

Given:

- that the cookie at idsrv has not expired
- the clients are using flow where redirects occur